# Как изменить текст ошибки валидации в форме django?

Tags: python, django

поле заголовка должно быть уникальным, поэтому выдаёт ошибку, но я не понимаю как я могу изменить текст ошибки.

[image: Form]

Код формы:

```
class NewPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'content', 'photo', 'category', 'tags']
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'content': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'rows': 12}),
            'category': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'tags': forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),

        }
        labels = {
            'content': 'Текст',
            'photo': 'Изображение',
        }
```

Код view:

```
class CreatePost(CreateView):
    form_class = NewPostForm
    template_name = 'blog/add_post.html'
    model = Post


    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = 'Add post'
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        form.instance.slug = slugify(form.instance.title)
        return super(CreatePost, self).form_valid(form)
```

Код models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, verbose_name='Заголовок')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True, verbose_name='URL', blank='True')
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Автор', blank=True)
    content = models.TextField(blank=False, verbose_name='Контент')
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, verbose_name='Фото')
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Просмоторы')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Дата создания')
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Дата обновления')
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Опубликовано')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='posts', verbose_name='Категория')
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True, related_name='posts', verbose_name='Теги')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Статья'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Статьи'
        ordering = ['-created_at']
```

Html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-6">
            <form method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark w-100" value="Post">Добавить новость</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Супер, нашёл ответ! Необходимо сделать проверку заголовка в форме.

```
 def clean_title(self):
        title = self.cleaned_data['title']
        if Post.objects.filter(title=title).exists():
            raise ValidationError('Статья с таким заголовком уже существует.')
        return title
```